# category selection with LASSO

Tags: categorical-data, feature-selection, lasso

Suppose one has two features: color = {R, G, B} and t-shirt size = {S, M, L} and wants to regress these features on the probability of a sale, call it p. So the model is p ~ color + size.

Now, the design matrix will have an intercept, and colors can be represented as

```
R -> [1 0 0]
G -> [1 1 0]
B -> [1 0 1]
```

Similarly for sizes. But color *and* size together will have 3x3=9 combinations, represented as (color first, then size):

```
R + S -> [1 0 0 0 0]
R + M -> [1 0 0 1 0]
R + L -> [1 0 0 0 1]
G + S -> [1 1 0 0 0]
G + M -> [1 1 0 1 0]
G + L -> [1 1 0 0 1]
B + S -> [1 0 1 0 0]
B + M -> [1 0 1 1 0]
B + L -> [1 0 1 0 1]
```

Now, when running LASSO on this, R + S are mixed together, i.e. say all coefficients but the intercept get shrunk to zero, which means that the likelihood is dependent on the color R and t-shirt size S, but how can one tell if R and/or S is more important? Is there another way to represent these categorical predictors without mixing two categories from different features in the intercept? Or is one stuck repeating the feature selection on R + S in this case to tell which one is more important? Is LASSO even the right algorithm to use for this setting, or would one just resort to classical backward/forward feature selection and then category selection using BIC or cross-validation as the error metric?

Comment: Use the group LASSO: [Yuan & Lin (2006), "Model selection and estimation in regression with grouped variables", *JRSS B*, **68**,1](http://pages.stat.wisc.edu/~myuan/papers/glasso.final.pdf)